# Aggregating all columns in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe containing more then 50 columns and a few million rows. I would like to group according to one of the columns and generate the averages and maxima for all remaining columns. To make it more understandable I am pasting a small snippet of that dataframe:

```
{'SystemID': {0: '95EE8B57',
1: '95EE8B57',
2: '5F891F03',
3: '5F891F03'},
'Day': {0: '06/08/2018', 1: '05/08/2018', 2: '04/08/2018', 3: '05/08/2018'},
'AlarmClass-S': {0: 4, 1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 0},
'AlarmClass-ELM': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 2}}
```

The output shall be

```
{'SystemID': {0: '95EE8B57',
1: '5F891F03'},
'AlarmClass-S-mean': {0: 3, 1: 2},
'AlarmClass-S-max': {0: 4, 1: 4},
'AlarmClass-ELM-mean': {0: 0, 1: 1},
'AlarmClass-ELM-max': {0: 0, 1: 2}
}
```

In this particular case the grouping is performed on SystemID. The aggregation (mean, max) is performed on all remaining columns apart from 'Day'.

How to do this efficiently?

I have a function which takes a column name and produces a dataframe with the aggregations (mean, max) for that column:

```
def mean_max(df, col_group, col_agg):
df_group = df.reset_index()[[col_group, col_agg]].groupby([col_group]).agg({col_agg:{col_agg + '_mean': 'mean', col_agg + '_max': 'max'}})
df_group.columns = df_group.columns.droplevel(0)
return df_group;
```

Theoretically I could just run this function iteratively over all +50 columns and then merge the +50 resulting dataframes. But my gut feeling is that this is not a good solution in terms of performance - and doesn't look elegant either.

So how can this be done more efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html)

```
cols = [i for i in df.columns if i != 'Day']
df1 = df.groupby('SystemID')[cols].agg(['mean','max'])

df1.columns = [' '.join(col) for col in df1.columns.values]

print (df1)

       AlarmClass-S mean    AlarmClass-S max  AlarmClass-ELM mean  AlarmClass-ELM max
SystemID                
5F891F03      2                   4                     1                 2
95EE8B57      3                   4                     0                 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Out of curiosity: why did you replace the line `df1.columns = df1.columns.map('{0[0]}-{0[1]}'.format)` with `df1.columns = [' '.join(col) for col in df1.columns.values]?` The original code is correct. Is there any specific reason why you prefer the second version?

Comment: @Nick I just think the second one is more easier to understand. You could use either one. :)